# How do I update the IE11 ActiveX Flash component included with Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, flash

[image]

On my MSI GT70 2PC laptop which originally came with Windows 8.1 and has since been updated to Windows 10, Secunia reports that my Adobe Flash installation is out of date. Weirdly enough, this concerns the Internet Explorer 11 Adobe Flash, which apparently uses a different component than the default Flash player. I have already tried to click the link, and it didn't do anything. I also don't have any Windows Updates waiting for me.

I have uninstalled Internet Explorer 11 for now because Flash 21.0.0.182 is a severe security risk and I don't use Internet Explorer anyway. However, this Flash Player section still remained in my computer according to Secunia. This remains a security risk. When navigating to the folder Secunia has located Flash in, this is what I find:

[image]

Running FlashUtil_ActiveX.exe gives a screen saying it will uninstall Flash from my computer, but it doesn't actually do anything. All files remain on my computer after the screen is gone.

I want to patch this instance of Flash, but I can't seem to figure out how to do so. How do I patch this version, preferably without reinstalling Windows 10?

Comment: Microsoft needs to release an Update

Comment: "I want to patch this instance of Flash" - You can't Microsoft has to.  So I suggest you disable Flash content until that happens.

Comment: @Ramhound I already did. I also already disabled IE11. If I could without breaking things, I would also disable Edge. I only use Flash in Chrome since that autoupdates. I don't even have Flash installed for other browsers.

Comment: Flash in IE and Edge also automatically update, since those updates are handled through Windows Update, just saying

Comment: @Ramhound My Windows Update was completely empty. I even checked a second time. My Flash on my desktop is also still 182, and the only thing that misses is a Windows Defender update that refuses to install.

Comment: If your talking about the most recent update to Flash, that likely hasn't been pushed by Microsoft, given it was released by Adobe after Tuesday.

Comment: @Ramhound Microsoft Patch Tuesday is next Tuesday, I think. I'll patch it then. I've disabled Internet Explorer until then, because if a program gets deceived into opening IE11 on a malicious flash page... /rant I don't understand why Redmond is not more proactive about pushing out security updates for 3rd party content. Having an outdated version of Flash for over 2 weeks is a security risk. Google pushes out Flash updates right away, and responsible sysadmins fast track Flash updates. /endrant